# How to allow my host IP address in the PostgreSQL pg_hba.conf file

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm having a PostgreSQL instance running on my local machine, listening on all the interfaces (`listen_addresses = '*'`), and Docker running a Rails application which needs to connect to this database.

Updating manually the `pg_hba.conf` file by adding a line allowing my IP address makes the application working.

Now, given my computer has the IP address 192.168.1.10, how to allow this IP address only in the `pg_hba.conf`, dynamically so that in case my IP address changes, the file is updated and PostgreSQL will continue accepting connections?

(My point is that I don't want to allow the 192.168.1.0 network, otherwise my colleagues are gonna be able to connect to my DB, which I don't want obviously :))

Comment: You can use a hostname in `pg_hba.conf`. If your computer is reachable through a hostname (e.g. because you are using DNS) then this will adjust to your dynamic IP address. Btw: if you don't give you colleagues the database user's password they can't connect either)

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name for this suggestion